# Why does my code output an extra "0" after finding the most frequent integer in an array?

Tags: java

An example of integers entered would be: 5 9 2 2 1 4 5 5 -1 and my code's output is "5 0". In this example array, I only need it to display "5  ". Try it yourself with any combination of integer input, ending your input with a -1 and you'll get the most frequent integer with a zero. Any ideas why my code does this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in); 

        int[] b = new int[21];

        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; ++i) { //integer input from user
            b[i] = scnr.nextInt();
            if (b[i] == -1) {    //array input stops when input is -1
                break;
            }
        }
        int maxcount = 0;
        int element_having_max_freq;
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; ++i) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < b.length; ++j) {
                if (b[i] == b[j]) {
                    count = count + 1;
                }
            }

            if (count > maxcount) {
                maxcount = count;
                element_having_max_freq = b[i];
                System.out.println(element_having_max_freq+ " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you return then?

Answer (score 0):

Your array is of size `21` and initialized as all zeros. All numbers you don't overwrite with the user input will remain zeros, which means that in the case of your test input `5 9 2 2 1 4 5 5 -1`, you get another 12 zeros.

Try placing a breakpoint after the part of the code that parses the user input and have a look at `b`.